# ASP.NET Identity and SignalR getting user

Tags: asp.net, signalr, asp.net-identity

I have ASP.NET Identity for logging in. I also have a SignalR Hub. My ApplicationUser for Identity has a custom field that I want to access in my SignalR Hub. In the Hub I have access to Context.User.Identity which shows everything is authenticated OK so it's somehow related to the ApplicationUser but it's not of type ApplicationUser so I can't get my custom fields. I've tried casting with no success.

Inside a Hub function:

```
Application user = (ApplicationUser)Context.User;
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can get my ApplicationUser object from inside a SignalR Hub?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should get your custom fields from the database.

```
_db.Users.Find(id);
```

Comment: what is _db and what is id.  how is this the accepted answer with an upvote.  From a signalr hub, how would one get to the application user manager if using owin for example.

Comment: More importantly what is ID, how are you supposed to get ID when you get that from the identity object... which is null when using singalR.